# Error downloading the Sceptre

Tags: python, python-2.7, sceptre

Below is the error when I am trying to install the particular version(1.2.1) of sceptre not the latest version,Please advise. Thanks.

$ pip install -e sceptre-1.2.1

sceptre-1.2.1 should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

Answer (score 0):

So the pip -e flag (edit mode) is maybe not doing what you think it should do here.

If you want to install a specific version of a package using pip you should do:

pip install sceptre==1.2.1

If you have installed sceptre globally across your system, rather than using a virtualenv then you may need to uninstall that package to use this specific version, but it is best to use a virtualenv.

Comment: after executing the above command below is the error shown.       
 tarfile.ReadError: empty file

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-nzpock\sceptre\

Comment: @sam can you provide some information about your local environment? Also, are you using a virtualenv for this? Executing the above command in a clean virtual env will work.